# Pop Up login Forms for LoginToBoggan

Tags: forms, users, javascript, authentication-authorization

I am using **LoginToBoggan Module** to unable anonymous user to register using self created password.

Now in some other page I want a **popup login form**. I have tried using other module like modal forms, but these seems not to work.

Please show me the right way to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try [Popup forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_forms) or [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) modules. These provide this functionality.